# Return ++a is different than return a++, why?

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with some code when I discovered something odd. I had the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int add_one_return(int a) {
    return a++;
}
void add_one_ref(int &a) {
    a++;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int a1 = 5;
    int a2 = 5;
    a1 = add_one_return(a1);
    add_one_ref(a2);
    std::cout << a1 << " " << a2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I ran it the program printed `5 6`. I went back and changed `add_one_return` to:

```
int add_one_return(int a) {
    return ++a;
}
```

and it worked! Why does `++a` work but not `a++`? Is there ever an advantage to `a++`, because I also hear that in a for loop you want to use `for(int i = 0; i < someVar; ++i) {}`, so why `a++` at all?

Comment: Naturally, the two results are different. Essentially, `add_one_return` is equivalent to `int add_one_return(int a) { return a; }` because post-increment of `a` is ignored.

Comment: There are two questions here.  "Why do they give different results" is easily answered by the duplicate as "because they are different operators".  The other question is more interesting: "when do you need the post-increment form".  The duplicate doesn't really address that.

Comment: Look at `C++ preincrement and postincrement`, you will find out the difference and what you want to use where.

Answer (score 4):

- `a++` returns what `a` was before, and then increments it, so originally your function would just return the argument and then add one.
- `++a` increments the variable and then returns, which is what you want here.